# jessenger mongodb case insensitive query search

Tags: mongodb, laravel

I have 1 issue with mongodb query search with exact values. i want to get collections irrespective of case sensitive. for this i found some querys like below. its working fine.

```
db.applications.find({"blocks.HOSPITAL_INFO.data.name": new RegExp('^VIKRAM$', 'i')});
```

in laravel i am using jessengers. . above query i can write as raw query in laravel.

but my issue is when ever i am using $In:{'a','b'} like this how can i write regex for this. FYI 'a','b' are dynamic array values. so how can i write regex for these array values?

Answer (score 0):

The query in MongoDB would be something like this:

```
db.applications.find({"blocks.HOSPITAL_INFO.data.name":
   {$in:[new RegExp('^a$', 'i'),new RegExp('^b$', 'i')]}});
```

OR, alternatively:

```
db.applications.find({"blocks.HOSPITAL_INFO.data.name":
   {$in:[/^a$/i,/^b$/i]}});
```

...where a & b are your dynamic variables.

I'm not very familiar with Laravel, but I'm guessing it would look something like this:

```
$applications = Application::whereIn('blocks.HOSPITAL_INFO.data.name',
   [new MongoRegex('^a$/i'), new MongoRegex('^b$/i')])->get();
```